# How do I start a service which is defined in a different package?

Tags: android, service, android-intent

I have two apps, one runs in namespace com.gtosoft.voyager and the other is com.gtosoft.dash. From com.gtosoft.dash I would like to start up the service which is defined in com.gtosoft.voyager...

I think I need an intent, but what arg(s) would I pass to the intent before kicking it off with startService()?

If they were in the same package I could just use

```
Intent svc=new Intent (SettingsActivity.this,VoyagerService.class);
startService(svc);
```

Snippet of Manifest which defines the service

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/voyagercarlogo" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">

    <provider android:name="com.gtosoft.voyager.VoyagerCProvider" 
        android:authorities="com.gtosoft.voyager"/>

    <service android:name=".VoyagerService"/>

    <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" 
            android:label="Voyager"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's a string of fully qualified namespace you're after.

Comment: That makes sense, but what would the string have to be? com.gtosoft.voyager.????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would set up an `<intent-filter>` on the service, with a custom action, and then use it in your `Intent` to start or bind to that service. You can see an example of that in this pair of [client](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/RemoteClient/) and [service](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/RemoteService/) sample projects.

Answer (score 13):

While CommonsWare's answer was correct back in April of 2010, things have a changed and you need to actually setComponent to start a service in another application.  For instance,

**Activity in com.xyz.app1:**

```
Intent i = new Intent();
String pkg = "com.xyz.app2";
String cls = "com.xyz.app2.MyService";
i.setComponent(new ComponentName(pkg, cls));
startService(i);
```